# upgrading SQLite-net to SQLite.net - create SQLiteConnection

Tags: xamarin, database-connection, sqlite-net

I used to open my `SQLiteConnection` in my shared project as following:

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection("MyDb.db3");
```

The constructor has been changed to the following signature:

```
    public SQLiteConnection(ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, string databasePath, bool storeDateTimeAsTicks = true, IBlobSerializer serializer = null, IDictionary<string, TableMapping> tableMappings = null, IDictionary<Type, string> extraTypeMappings = null, IContractResolver resolver = null);
    public SQLiteConnection(ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, string databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, bool storeDateTimeAsTicks = true, IBlobSerializer serializer = null, IDictionary<string, TableMapping> tableMappings = null, IDictionary<Type, string> extraTypeMappings = null, IContractResolver resolver = null);
```

I was not able to find any examples/documentation on how to implement this in my shared library.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quite easy once you found it. The namespace `SQLite.Net.Platform` containt the implementation for the `ISQLitePlatform`interface.

I had to implement this in de platform specific libraries instead of the shared one.

```
new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), Path.Combine(path, db));
```

Comment: This seems outdated now. There is no SQLite.Net.Platform.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson found a solution to this?