# I am trying to open a connection to my SQLite Database in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, database-connection, sqlite.net

I am using SQLite.Net-PCL (trying to) in my WPF application.

I am stuck trying to make a connection.

I have this:

```
var connector = new SQLiteConnection(S, "My_DB_Path");
```

where 
    'S' is of type:

```
SQLite.Net.Interop.ISQLitePlatform
```

But how do I make this setting - confused...

Comment: What do you mean *But how do I make this setting*

Comment: well, give me an example line of code for this?  What value do I pass in?

Comment: please: as not sure what value to pass in?

Comment: [SQLite connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/)

Comment: @Izzy thank you but I am using this framework : I am using SQLite.Net-PCL

Answer (score 1):

Googling around, it seems that the `SQLiteConnection` class has a constructor that just accepts a string. Can you use that one instead?

Something like:

```
new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;")
```

Comment: Hi, the sqlite framework I am using does not expect just the connection string. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQLiteConnection as follows

string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "db_Name.db");

```
        db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);

        if (db != null)
            db.CreateTable<Table_Name>();
```

Comment: Hi, the sqlite framework I am using does not expect just the connection string. :(

Comment: Which versioon of sqlite are you using?

Comment: Hi, it is not a matter of version it is a matter of framework.  I am using the SQLite.net PCL framework at : https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

Comment: var connection = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, DATABASE_NAME));    //Try to use this.

Comment: Thanks, but when I put that in I get: The type or namespace name 'SQLitePlatformWinRT' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: Please check this link                                      https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/

Comment: thanks but there does not seem to be any sample code for a wpf c# desktop application to make a connection

Answer (score 0):

In Android, I'm using `new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid(), path);`

For WPF maybe you can use a generec platform. [See this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32092361/1509954)